# Encrypting Java then Decrypting C# AES256 Encryption with HMACSHA256, Padding is invalid

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I'm currently running into an issue where our decryption portion of our C# site is having trouble with the padding with the encrypted string from java. The .Net code throws this error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed". The _signKey and _encKey are both 64 bytes.

```
public String encryptString(String plainText) {
        byte[] ciphertext;
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        byte[] plainBytes = plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String _signKey = "****************************************************************";
        String _encKey = "****************************************************************";



        try {
            Mac sha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            SecretKeySpec shaKS = new SecretKeySpec(_signKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA256");
            sha256.init(shaKS);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecureRandom randomSecureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
            randomSecureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
            IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            byte[] sessionKey = sha256.doFinal((_encKey + iv).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            // Perform Encryption
            SecretKeySpec eks = new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, eks, ivParams);

            ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
            System.out.println("ciphertext= " + new String(ciphertext));
            // Perform HMAC using SHA-256 on ciphertext
            SecretKeySpec hks = new SecretKeySpec(_signKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA256");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(hks);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            outputStream2.write(iv);
            outputStream2.write(ciphertext);
            outputStream2.flush();
            outputStream2.write(mac.doFinal(outputStream2.toByteArray()));
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(outputStream2.toByteArray());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return plainText;
    }
```

Does does encrypt the string properly as far as I can tell. We cannot change any code on the .Net side to decrypt this because this is being used today.

```
public static string DecryptString(string ciphertext)
    {
        using (HMACSHA256 sha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_signKey)))
        {
            // Convert message to bytes
            byte[] encBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);

            // Get arrays for comparing HMAC tags
            byte[] sentTag = new byte[sha256.HashSize / 8];
            byte[] calcTag = sha256.ComputeHash(encBytes, 0, (encBytes.Length - sentTag.Length));

            // If message length is too small return null
            if (encBytes.Length < sentTag.Length + _ivLength) { return null; }

            // Copy tag from end of encrypted message
            Array.Copy(encBytes, (encBytes.Length - sentTag.Length), sentTag, 0, sentTag.Length);

            // Compare tags with constant time comparison, return null if no match
            int compare = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sentTag.Length; i++) { compare |= sentTag[i] ^ calcTag[i]; }
            if (compare != 0) { return null; }

            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Set parameters
                csp.BlockSize = _blockBits;
                csp.KeySize = _keyBits;
                csp.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                csp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                // Copy init vector from message
                var iv = new byte[_ivLength];
                Array.Copy(encBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

                // Derive session key
                byte[] sessionKey = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_encKey + iv));

                // Decrypt message
                using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = csp.CreateDecryptor(sessionKey, iv))
                {
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(encBytes, iv.Length, encBytes.Length - iv.Length - sentTag.Length));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is anything that sticks out it would be appreciated for the reply.

Comment: Typically an incorrect padding error really just means the decryption failed, that the key, encrypted data, IV, etc were incorrect and/or the encoding did not match the implementation.

Comment: Which is really confusing to me. We do a comparison above to make sure the tags are correct. And I've compared the vectors to what we were sending over from Java and they were identical. This is why I'm hung out. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read all your code, but this line in Java:

```
byte[] sessionKey = sha256.doFinal((_encKey + iv).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

does nothing useful or sensible. The "+" operator does string concatenation, but `iv` is a `byte[]`, not a String. So java uses `iv.toString()`, which simply returns a String containing something like `[B@1188e820` which is meaningless in this context.

Comment: Okay thanks for that actually! I'm fairly new to java so I'm figuring this out as I go. On our .Net portion we are using this 
                // Derive session key
                byte[] sessionKey = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_encKey + iv));

I'm trying to mimic this from our .NET side. If that helps. Any ideas about how to accomplish the same thing in Java?

Comment: By the way I figured this out. I appreciate your help a lot. Literally had to add System.Byte[] at the end to make it work properly. Our .Net side was not working as properly as people thought.

Answer (score -2):

Refer four java code and DotNet code:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); //Java
csp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; //.Net
```

You are essentially using different padding, that is the probable source of error; however, there is an alternate view, [Refer this great post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43489/how-does-aes-ctr-pkcs5padding-works-when-the-bits-to-encrypt-is-more-than-8-bits) and [this for general fundamentals on padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography))

The cipher suites supported by deafult Oracle JVM implementation [are here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)

If you notice it does not have 'AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding', a PKCS#7 padding implementation is available in sun.security package, [refer this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/pkcs7-encoding-in-java-without-external-libs-like-bouncycastle-etc), otherwise you could use [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) packages. It would be recommendable to use Bouncy Castle as com.sun package are generally considered unsupported.

Comment: PKCS#7 and PKCS#5 padding are the same in practice with the difference only in the definition. See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7), in particular: "*PKCS#5 padding is identical to PKCS#7 padding, except that it has only been defined for block ciphers that use a 64-bit (8 byte) block size. In practice the two can be used interchangeably.*". Many implementations were just to lazy to include n PKCS#7 definition when adding AES and just decided to use the PKCS#5 definition in order to add confusion such as this.

Comment: @Zaph thanks for the reply you are completely correct. I've realized this awhile ago. The answer provided above isn't correct